# PHP PDO date time formats

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

So I am using PHP PDO to load a class I have created called 'User' from mysql.  My object contains several fields including 3 date fields.  But for some reason, when I dump the object (using var_export) then I can see that the dates are stored differently.   1 as unix time and the others as date strings

Here is the dump;

```
'createdtime' => '2013-04-19 09:36:42',

'logintime' => '2013-04-25 01:32:50',

'lastactiontime' => '1366880785',
```

All three fields are defined in MYSQL as DATETIME, so I don't understand why this has occured.

Any ideas?

My PHP code is;

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * from user where id=:id');        
$STH->bindParam(':id', $id);
$STH->execute();        

$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');               
$user = $STH->fetch();
```

I must have done something wrong somewhere, but what?

Comment: Are there any magic setter methods in `User`? For example `__set()`. Also try to fetch as associative array first and see what the output is.

Comment: I have not used any magic setters in User.

Comment: When I load as an associate array then I get the the right data!  createdtime' => '2013-04-19 09:36:42', 'logintime' => '2013-04-25 01:32:50', 'lastactiontime' => '2013-04-25 10:06:25'

Comment: Then there must be some formatting of the date to a UNIX timestamp somewhere in the class user.